# Wifi hotspot without internet

Tags: applications, wi-fi, settings

With newer versions of Android and for certain manufacturers they always tries to make sure your WiFi has internet. I guess this is an OK feature if multiple known Wifi AP is available.

However the issue is that we have a product that creates a WiFi hotspot much like dashcams do.

The question is, is there a way to tell Android (via our App),that you know you are connecting to a WiFi network without internet so Android should stop controlling the WiFi "smartly" to try to get Internet regardless?

Comment: Since you're apparently programming an app, you might want to check out [so], the programmers there will be much more familiar with writing Android apps.